# Pass output from one workflow step to another in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-workflows

I am trying to orchestrate a GCP workflow to first run a query in Big Query to get some metadata (name & id) that would then be passed to another step in the workflow that starts a dataflow job given those parameters as input.

So step by step I want something like:

1. Result = Query("SELECT ID & name from biq query table")
2. Start dataflow job: Input(result)

Is this possible or is there a better solution?

Comment: Your `Dataflow` job can directly read from `Bigquery` via `BigqueryIO`, why do you want to do that in a separated step in your orchestrator ?

Comment: Did you try creating dataflow job using BigQuery IO connector as mentioned [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#reading-from-bigquery)?

Comment: Yes but the result from the query mentioned above is to get data that will be pipeline options for the real job. So the purpose of the first query is more to get metadata to know which jobs to run.  @MazlumTosun

Answer (score 1):

I propose you 2 solutions and I hope it can help.

**- Solution 1 :**
If you have an orchestrator like `Airflow` in `Cloud Composer` :

- Use task with a `BigQueryInsertJobOperator` in `Airflow`, this operator allows to execute a query to `Bigquery`
- Pass the result to a second Operator via `xcom`
- 2 second operator is an operator that extends `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator`
- When you extend `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator`, you override the `execute` method. In this method, you can recover the data from previous operator via `xcom pull` as `Dict`
- Pass this `Dict` as pipeline options to your operator that extends `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator`
- The `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator` will launch your `Dataflow` job

An example of operator with `execute` method :

```py
class CustomBeamOperator(BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator):

    def __init__(
            self,
            your_field
            ...
            **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.your_field = your_field
        ...

    def execute(self, context):
        task_instance = context['task_instance']
        your_conf_from_bq =  task_instance.xcom_pull('task_id_previous_operator')
       
        operator = BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator(
            runner='DataflowRunner',
            py_file='your_dataflow_main_file.py',
            task_id='launch_dataflow_job',
            pipeline_options=your_conf_from_bq,
            py_system_site_packages=False,
            py_interpreter='python3',
            dataflow_config=DataflowConfiguration(
               location='your_region'
            )
        )
        
        operator.execute(context)
```

**- Solution 2 :**

If you don't have an orchestrator like `Airflow`

- You can use the same virtual env that launch your actual `Dataflow` job but add Python `Bigquery` client as package : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries
- Create a main `Python` file that retrieves your conf from `Bigquery` table as `Dict` via `Bigquery` client
- Generate with Python the command line to launch your Dataflow job with the previous conf retrieved from database, example with Python :

```bash
python -m folder.your_main_file \
        --runner=DataflowRunner \
        --conf1=conf1/ \
        --conf2=conf2
        ....
        --setup_file=./your_setup.py \
```

- Launch the previous `Python` command with `Python` `suprocess`
- You can also maybe try this api to launch `Dataflow` job : https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-dataflow-client/
  I didn't tried it.

I think the solution with `Airflow` is easier.